# How to add elements at corresponding indices in R vectors?

Tags: r, vector, addition, indices

Let us say I have two vectors in R that are numerical, `v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)` and `v2 = c(2,4,6,8,10)`. When I add `v1` and `v2`, I do not want to append `v2` onto the end of `v1`, I want to sum the corresponding indices so it looks like the following: `c(3,6,9,12,15)`.

However, I will be doing this an unknown amount of time so I might not just be adding `v1` and `v2` (2 vectors), but also `v3` and `v4` and so on (many vectors).

I am hoping this is rather simple, so if there is easy way to do this in R please let me know. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with `v1 + v2 + v3 ....`.

Comment: Will you have a list of vectors to add up? Or will they be given to you in some other way?

Comment: `Reduce(\`+\`, list(v1,v2))` I suppose.

Comment: @RonakShah that's exactly what I want, and it's so simple too! I tried append and c(v1,v2) which did not give me what I wanted. My bad for not thinking of that. Thanks!

Comment: @G5W yes. It will be a list of vectors.

Comment: Then @thelatemail 's solution is a good one.